# Shell: Extract specific blocks from an XML file

Tags: xml, linux, shell, xml-parsing

I have a xml file with a same tag occuring multiple times continuously. I need to extract only that set of tags as an array.

xml file looks like:

```
...
<otherTags>
<myTag>
  <abc/>
</myTag>
<myTag>
  <abc/>
</myTag>
<myTag>
  <abc/>
</myTag>
<otherTags>
...
```

My output should look like:

```
<myTag>
  <abc/>
</myTag>

<myTag>
  <abc/>
</myTag>

<myTag>
  <abc/>
</myTag>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format is that simple, use

```
$ awk '/<myTag>/,/<\/myTag>/' inputfile
<myTag>
  <abc/>
</myTag>
<myTag>
  <abc/>
</myTag>
<myTag>
  <abc/>
</myTag>
```

But there are tools designed for parsing complex XML files, which you should use if it gets more complicated. One is called [xml-grep](http://xml-coreutils.sourceforge.net/xml-grep_man.html). You might also want to familiarize yourself with [XPath technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath).

Comment: Thanks Jen,it worked. But this is what I am trying to do, I want to use this shell inside tcl i.e, set buff [ exec awk '/<myTag>/,/<\/myTag>/' inputfile ].  But my tcl prompt says, awk: invalid char ''' in expr.

Comment: @Ashwin In tcl you have different rules for quoting. This does the trick: `set buff [ exec awk {/<myTag>/,/<\/myTag>/} inputfile ]`.